# EPPLUS - Ajustar Texto a celda

Tags: c#, epplus

Quisiera saber si se puede a justar un texto largo al tamaño de la celda en usando EPPLUS.dll
[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Comment: pero alli ya estas ajustando el texto a la celda, o lo que necesitas es expandir la celda para que el texto se vea a lo largo ?

Comment: Ajustar el texto a la celda. Le quiero poner un ancho fijo a la columna y que el texto se acomode.

Comment: Me inmagino que la libreria debera tener alguna propiedad `WrapText` en la cual puedas modificar el estilo de la celda, ya leiste la documentacion de ***EPPlus***.

Comment: En la documentacion, tienen un ejemplo donde seleccionan un rango de celda y le activan el `WrapText`, [ver ejemplo](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/e7230ed0450ff9985b4c8a159f74ca1c348d6e67/SampleApp/Sample7.cs#L74).

Comment: el que se acomode ya esta implementado y se visualiza en la imagen, lo que entiendo falta es que puedas definir un ancho para la columna

Comment: Tienes razon, es que es dificil entender a que se refiere con ***a justar un texto largo al tamaño de la celda*** y a parte de eso pareciera que lo ractaron los ovnis, a ver cuando se aparece.....(-_-).....

Answer (score 2):

Sé que es una pregunta vieja, pero a lo que se refería el OP, si no malinterpreto, es a la opción `Ajustar Texto`

Para esto, sólo basta con setear la propiedad `WrapText` dentro del objeto `Style` de la celda correspondiente.

Por ejemplo:

```
var pkg = new ExcelPackage(fileStream);
var ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.WrapText = true;
```

De esta manera, la celda `A1` tendrá la opción `Ajustar Texto` activa, por ende, se visualizará como en la imagen con la que ejemplificó el OP.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar algo como ser

```
double columnWidth = 50;
worksheet.Column(1).Width = columnWidth;
```

para definir el ancho de la columna

[Resizing rows and columns](https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/27332/resizing-rows-and-columns)

Tambien podrias ver el auto fit

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:K20"].AutoFitColumns();
```

[Autofit columns](https://riptutorial.com/epplus/example/26412/autofit-columns)